# How do i find if a specific Timezone is observing DST using PHP?

Tags: php

I have users from all around the world using our system.  Each of them has chosen their local timezone (recorded as UTC e.g. UM8 etc)

All of our data is saved using UTC as the standard so all data can be compared.

I can show the date/time local to the user using codeigniter's gmt_to_local() function ( http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html )  but it asks for DST = True/False.

How can i look up the Timezone to see if it is observing DST currently?

Comment: If you haven't stored their timezone then why not push the UTC to the browser and change it to local time in javascript. You might not know their timezone but the client does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And addition to Corbin's answer (+1 to him):

If you had real timezone name, then you could use the code like

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland'));
echo $date->format('I'); // 0

$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $date->format('I'); // 1
```

Which means that in Auckland (New Zealand) it is not a DST, and in London it is

Comment: Excellent, that makes a lot of sense.  I'm designing the new version of the app at the moment so I'll get them to select from a TimeZone name list instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You don't have enough information if you just recorded a UTC offset. You need a country specific timezone as it's possible for two countries to be UTC X when not DST and then only one of them shift to a different offset.

As a concrete example, when DST is not in effect, New York and Colombia are both UTC -5. During DST New York changes to UTC -4. So, if you have UTC -5 how do you know if you should use UTC -4 without location information (NY would switch, this DST=true, but Colombia would not)?  This is a rather bad example, but first two locations that came to mind :).